# Multiplatform processor affinity

Tags: c#, .net

Lets take this simple code that will set current application to use only first core:

```cs
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
p.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)0x0000000000000001;
```

But Visual Studio says that this is platform dependent API and it will work only on Linux and Windows.

In my current scenario I won't use it on anything else than Windows, but I wanted to ask out of curiosity how can this be written so it will work on all possible (that .NET 6 allows) platforms.

Comment: Either add another OS-specific library or do a native call. The fact that .NET devs doesn't bother to do that hint either the API may not exist, or harder/less reliable than expected.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/platform-compat-analyzer